# meaning of init(function_pointer): bgp_init(function)

Tags: c++11

I have gone through the below code. can u please tell me what is the meaning of init(function_pointer): bgp_init(function)

```
struct protocol proto_bgp = {
  name:         "BGP",
  template:     "bgp%d",
  attr_class:       EAP_BGP,
  preference:       DEF_PREF_BGP,
  init:         bgp_init,
  start:        bgp_start,
  shutdown:     bgp_shutdown,
};
```

Comment: It's definitely C, seems to be an old snippet from the [`Bird`](https://github.com/jkjuopperi/bird/blob/42a6f58ab89fd7f1cbe7fbc6d5208d85636c98c1/proto/bgp/bgp.c#L1149) project.

Comment: Yes can u help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

The `{...}` followed by the object is called initializer list. In this case, `init` is being initialized to `bgp_init`.

Comment: But why semicolon is in between init and bgp_init. what semicolon indicates here?

Comment: That is the initializer syntax. Please refer to [this artile](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list).

Comment: Thanks for ur reply mahesh. But what u sent is initializer syntax for class. which is c++, but the code which i mentioned here is completely on c (based on structures). If u get to know what it means please share it with me.

Comment: @chinmay It has the same meaning. Left hand side before the colon is the member of the struct, right hand side is the value.